# Concatenate 1000 CSV file directly in Google Cloud Storage? Without duplicated headers?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Is it possible to concatenate 1000 CSV file that have header into one file with no duplicated header directly in Google Cloud Storage?  I could easily do this by downloading the file into my local hard drive but I would prefer to do it natively in Cloud Storage.

They all have same columns, and have header row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote [an article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/merge-clean-transform-your-csvs-easily-with-bigquery-3a73c0c26d57) to handle CSV files with BigQuery. To avoid several files, and if the volume is less than 1Gb, the recommended way is the following

1. Create a temporary table in BigQuery with all your CSV.
2. Use the [Export API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data) (not the export function)

Let me know if you need more guidance.

Comment: Very neat, thank you for describing this solution

Comment: Wait, I tried your solution, it break up the results into multiple csv files, how do I export it into one file?

Comment: If you use the solution in my article, yes, you will have several CSVs. That's why I said: don't use the function, but the export API. The export API allows you to export a table (and not a query)  to only one file, if size is less than 1Gb

Comment: Ah ok I see, understood